# Getting Read Time out in Native Bigquery Zeppelin Interpreter

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-zeppelin

I have configured **Native Bigquery Zeppelin interpreter** to access datasets in Google-cloud Bigquery. 
I am able to run select queries from the zeppelin notebooks without any issues using Bigquery interpreter.

But when I tried to create table (using CTAS query)in the Bigquery from zeppelin notebook. I got **read time out** error in zeppelin notebook. 
Whereas the table got created successfully in the Bigquery, I am able to see that the CTAS query triggered in Bigquery from the Query history and got succeeded after 2 mins.

I have tried increasing the "**zeppelin.bigquery.wait_time**" property in big query interpreter setting to 240000 ms. But no luck.

Am I missing anything in Zeppelin Interpreter Configuration ?

Zeppelin version - 0.8.1